# How to summon zombies at random chances

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a recreation of *zombie siege* and everything is going great.

Except for the spawning zombies. I would like to have them spawn randomly at the end of my tunnel, but the only random generators I've found online are too slow.
Not to mention unreliable and inefficient.

Can anyone help me come up with a random generator that would suit my needs?

Comment: can you tell us what you already found and what it is that you need exactely? because your post is pretty vague as to what exactely you want.

Comment: Sorry for that, I need a random generator for minecraft. One that spits out zombies randomly that goes faster than say, one that has a chicken and two pressure plates.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Yes, I've tried. I'm just stuck on this part of spawning the zombies.

Comment: "goes faster" - still not specific enough. *when* do you want them to spawn, *how fast* do you want them to spawn, *where* do you want them to spawn, *what are the circumstances*, these are questions that you should answer before we can really make any attempt to actually help you and not just take a guess out into the blue what you might need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making a custom mob spawner with mcstacker.bimbimma.com. Just remember to change the command type at the top to `Spawner`.